# Range.insertNode() without triggering "selectionchange"

Tags: javascript, range, dom-events, selection

How to insert a node after a selection without triggering any `selectionchange` event.

I got the range from `Selection.getRangeAt(0)`.

[Insert HTML after a selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597116/insert-html-after-a-selection) this preserves selection but still triggers `selectionchange` event. If I delete the last part:

```
expandedSelRange.setEndAfter(lastNode);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(expandedSelRange);
```

then Chrome preserves without triggering but Firefox doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround.

Basically, I was manipulating a Range object. If I can detach one then I can manipulate it however I want. So I made a design choice and passed the detached range as a parameter in the function.

After some trial and error, I used this which works:

```
var r = range.cloneRange(); r.detach();
```

Then you can manipulate r without affecting the DOM.

Comment: Note that detach() no longer does anything.  This should still work without it, though, because cloneRange() is creating a new object and changes to that new object shouldn't affect selection, etc.